# For Loop based on current list of dataframes R

Tags: r

These functions work alone, however not when introduced into a loop.

```
for (i in ls()) {
   names(i) <- gsub(" ","_",names(i))
   names(i) <- gsub("\\(","_",names(i))
   names(i) <- gsub("\\)","_",names(i))
   names(i) <- gsub(" ","_",names(i))
   names(i) <- gsub("-","_",names(i))
   names(i) <- gsub("/","_",names(i))
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what are the names you have and what do you need?

Comment: Your `i` is likely an object when testing your code. It becomes a character string in the loop. Character strings don't have names. Replace all `names(i)` with `names(get(i))` to fix your code. Also, the regex can be simplified into one expression.